# URI vs Method names in Action class - Struts 2

Tags: struts2

In my Action class, I defined method names as follows:

```
public String doAddUser(){}
public String doDeleteUser(){}
```

in Struts.xml i've configured as follows:

```
<action name="*User" class="MyAction" method="do{1}User"></action>
```

From URI, if i request like AddUser or DeleteUser, its working. But i want to request like addUser or deleteUser (starts with lowercase letter). How can i acheive this?

Answer (score 1):

URLs are case-sensitive, so the following will make addUser and deleteUser work, but not AddUser and DeleteUser. If you want to support both, you will need to create multiple mappings, but I don't think you should strive for that.

```
<action name="*User" class="MyAction" method="{1}User"></action>

public String addUser(){}
public String deleteUser(){}
```

> Why i asked this question is, in Struts1.x, we have `LookupDispatchAction` concept. When user hits one url(for ex, addUser), we can call our defined method with whatever name(ie., doAddUser). In this case, we can solve my issue. But Struts 2.x, there is no possibility like that(as far as i know).

It sounds like you are looking for [dynamic method invocation](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.14/docs/action-configuration.html#ActionConfiguration-DynamicMethodInvocation). Basically, if you have an action mapped as `myAction`, then you can invoke the `addUser()` method by going to `myAction!addUser`. `myAction!execute` is equivalent to the default of just `myAction`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The approach you suggested tells that the URL and method name should be same. But i just want to change the case for method name.ie., if user hits addUser, i have to call AddUser method. Is there any other workaround just to ignore case sensitivity for method names without writing individual mappings like wildcard mappgings which are used to call multiple methods for multiple URLs with single action configuration.

Comment: Both URLs and method names are case sensitive, so I am unaware of any settings like what you describe. Also, be aware that `AddUser` as a method name deviates from the established coding conventions for the Java language.

Comment: Ok. Actually my method names are like this: for uri addUser, my method name is doAddUser(). I think this follows java naming convention. Why i asked this quesion is, in Struts1.x, we have LookupDispatchAction concept. When user hits one url(for ex, addUser), we can call our defined method with whatever name(ie., doAddUser). In this case, we can solve my issue. But Struts 2.x, there is no possibility like that(as far as i know). We can implement this by providing multiple mappings but i dont want that as in my case all mappings having same resut names (continued in next comment...)

Comment: ie;, all have  3 results success,input and error and all forwarded to same tiles layout. Based on some condition, im changing the display in the center jsp. If i define multiple mappings, i need to write these results in all mappings. So if there is a possibility like wildcard mappings my problem will be solved easily with single mapping. Anyway, thanx for your response.

Comment: I've revised my answer to discuss dynamic method invocation as an option for you.